# Adding dynamic table with empty input filed on button click using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, input

Facing issue while adding a dynamic table with text box value as blank
    Below is the plunker
    http://plnkr.co/edit/nSUlYSbPTButtXHEs3qY?p=preview
    step1:Intially a table (table1) with new fruit value a **GOVA** is added(ngmodel="newFruit" ).
    Step2:On click of addtables dynamic table (table2) is genrated with new fruit value a **GOVA** .
    Issue:When table 2 is added the new fruit value should be blank or null

```
Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: All your tables use the same 'fruit' variable to display fruits. you should define a fruit array into each table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your plunker, all of your tables use the same array of fruit.

I change your plunker to add an fruit array into each table : http://plnkr.co/edit/DwXw2DFF0qnsBs54lJjX?p=preview

```
$scope.tables = [{ name: "table", fruits: ['apple','mango','banana'] }];
```

Comment: Hi yoann but i want dynamic table with empty text box  when clicking on the add table  which is not happening

Comment: You just have to initialize text box with an empty string on table creation :)

Comment: My last plunker fix your issue ?

Comment: Hey Its worked for me still i have issues.I cant merge my dynamic data into table as you did

Comment: <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="fruit in table.fruits track by $index">{{ fruit }}</li>
    </ul>